# Need help deleting a directory

Tags: xubuntu, filesystem

I have a directory in my home directory (the one with My Documents, etc.) with a name that looks a bit like my username (random upper-lowercase alphabetical characters).  It suddenly appeared Tuesday, that when you open it it just loads forever, when you open up the properties window the size thing loads forever, and if you try to delete it it doesn't seem to work.  I think it was created by BleachBit, which crashed near the end of wiping free space, and thus, because of the crashing, the file is corrupted and won't do anything.

How do I delete it?

I have Xubuntu, by the way.

Comment: Try `rm -rf <directory>`, if not working then`sudo rm -r <directory>` or `sudo rm -rf <directory>`

Answer (score 1):

> and if you try to delete it it doesn't seem to work

If a normal `rm -rf {dir}` does not work do a disk check first. Easiest to do that would be (this will reboot your system and do a disk check during the boot):

```
sudo touch /forcefsck
sudo reboot
```

And try a `rm -rf {dir}` again. If that still does not work try it from a live dvd. Don't kill the command and let it run for a little while.

It is possible that there is an error with the file system where a dir inside a dir points to a dir above (and making an endless loop). The disk check should fix that.